routing traffic through second wireguard server
I have 3 wireguard nodes. one acts as "main-server", the second as "web-gateway" and the third as "client".
The "client" and the "web-gateway" connect to the "main-server". The "client" sends all it´s data to the "main-sever". From there the "main-server" is forwarding the tcp 80/443 data from the "client" to the "web-gateway". So far so good.
The problem now is that I am not able to route the data on the "web-gateway" that is coming throught the wireguard interface (wg0) to the real network interface (eth0).
Tcpdump is showing the data on wg0 interface on "web-gateway" but there is no data on eth0 interface. So the data is not reaching the internet.
port forwarding is active on both systems:
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

iptables rules on "web-gateway":
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

wg0.conf of "web-gateway":
[Interface] 
PrivateKey = *** 
ListenPort = 21000 
Address = 10.8.0.100/32 
DNS = 10.8.0.1 

[Peer] 
PublicKey = *** 
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0 
Endpoint = ***:443 
PersistentKeepalive = 25

wg0.conf of "main-server":
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
ListenPort = 443
PrivateKey = ***

[Peer]
PublicKey = ***
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.100/32

iptables rules on "main-server":
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.100
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.8.0.100 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.100
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -d 10.8.0.100 -j MASQUERADE


Please add all the confs (with the keys redacted), especially when you can't differentiate IP forwarding and port forwarding.

added the config.
